# The macro definition prevents me from using other key lengths

Tags: c, encryption, macros

I have written an encryption algorithm that has three key lengths for users to choose from, but the current problem is:
I cannot change the length of the key after compiling this encryption algorithm into a library file.

like this:

cipher.h

```c
#define CIPHER_128
#define CIPHER_256
#define CIPHER_384

#if defined(CIPHER_384)
#define CIPHER_KEYLEN 48
#elif defined(CIPHER_256)
#define CIPHER_KEYLEN 32
#else
#define CIPHER_KEYLEN 16
#endif
```

cipher.c

```c
#include "cipher.h"

#if defined(CIPHER_384)
// code
#elif defined(CIPHER_256)
// code
#else
// code
#endif
```

Assuming that when I compile this encryption algorithm into a library file, the content in the `cipher.h` is as follows:

```c
#define CIPHER_128
// #define CIPHER_256
// #define CIPHER_384
```

So I won't be able to use the two key lengths CIPHER_256 and CIPHER_384 in the code. (Even if I uncomment the macro definition that has been commented out)

That is to say, when compiling the algorithm into a library, which key length is defined, then when using this library file in the future, only this key length can be used.

I tried to add a judgment method, but it didn't work:

```c
#define CIPHER_256 1
// ...

#if defined(CIPHER_256) && (CIPHER_256 == 1)
// ...
#endif
```

I also came up with an idea to add a keylen member to the data type structure of this encryption algorithm, where the user specifies the key length to be used for each encryption and decryption, but I am not sure if this is necessary.

Here are my compilation instructions:

```bash
gcc -c cipher.c
ar cr libcipher.dll cipher.o

gcc src/test.c -I includes/cipher -L. -lcipher -o test
```

Comment: I think it may be necessary to add a keylen member, as some developers of encryption algorithms do.

Comment: You can't use compile-time conditions if you want to vary something at run time.

Comment: @Barmar May I ask for a specific explanation? I am very confused about this situation now. Thank you.

Comment: All the `#ifdef` are processed when you compile the program. So you only get one set of code in the resulting executable.

Comment: @Barmar Is there a way to fix this problem without affecting performance? thank you.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using enumeration types.
like this:

```c
typedef enum {
    cioher_256,
    cipher_384,
    cipher_512
} cipher_mode;

static const nr[3] = {
    ...
};

static const keylen[3] = {
    ...
};

// function demo
void cipher(cipher_mode mode, ...)
{
     for(i = 0; i < nr[mode]; ++i)
     ...
}
```

Comment: The benefit of doing so is not to lose performance, and there are even many times when efficiency is faster than when using macro definitions before.

Answer (score 0):

A MACRO is resolved at compile time, actually at preprocessing time, so, when you compile your code into a library, there will no longer be a `CIPHER_KEYLEN` in the library. It will be replaced by the value the preprocessor assigned to it.

It will be one of the 3 values, and it will be fixed.

So, if you want the key size to be selected at runtime, you will need it to be a member variable of the key type. And then of course you will have to check key lengths match when performing operations on them.

If you want the entire program, to have only one global key length, it could be a global variable, or better a static variable of the class. But in this case, you want to only enable to set the value of the variable once, or have some way to invalidate previous keys generated with the previous key length.

This could be a way to only allow the modification once:

```c
static int key_length = 0;

void init(int length) {
    if (!key_length && length > 0) { //no initialized
        key_length = length;
    } else {
        //perform some error handling.
    }
}

int get_key_length() {
    return key_length;
}
```

You could also do things like setting a flag if a `Key` was already created, to no permit the `init` be called if a key was already created with the default (if any key length). Or if you don't want to set a default key length, you could throw an exception in the constructor/builder/factory method.

Comment: The code is not C.

Comment: the code is not C, And it affects the performance of the program in some sense.

Comment: You are totally right about it not being C, my bad, for some reason I cannot pinpoint, I believed it was a C++ question, I'll update the answer as soon as I am in the PC. Regarding the not being performance, I just provided a possible solution if it were decided to protect the user, I say that in the answer with other words. Meanwhile,the explanation part about the why it's still valid.